# Rails ActiveStorage Error - MessageVerifier-InvalidSignature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I'm working on a project that requires an `ActiveStorage` `has_many_attached :photos` situation on a `Location` model.

I have the code set up below, but when attempting to upload a form, I receive the following error:

```
ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature in 
                                 LocationsController#attach_photo
```

Is this the way to "add" a file to the set of attachments for a particular parent record (i.e: a `Location` record)?

#### `Location` Model

```rb
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many_attached :photos
  ...
end
```

#### Locations Controller

```rb
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def attach_photo
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    @location.photos.attach(params[:photo])
    redirect_to location_path(@location)
  end
  ...
end
```

#### View

```
<%= form_tag attach_photo_location_path(@location) do %>
  <%= label_tag :photo %>
  <%= file_field_tag :photo %>

  <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

#### View

```rb
resources :locations do
  member do
    post :attach_photo
  end
end
```

Comment: I've used the Direct Upload feature of ActiveStorage recently. What I like about this approach is that I don't have to write any code to handle the actual upload itself, Rails does it for me. Did you take this approach too? See the related guide here and let me know: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads – even though the docs make a reference to uploading to the cloud, it will work with locally stored files too.

Answer (score 27):

Make sure to add `multipart: true` in `form_tag`. It generates `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

`form_tag` by default not responsible for it, must have it (if attaching a file).

> multipart/form-data   No characters are encoded. This value is required
>   when you are using forms that have a file upload control

[image]

**Form:**

```
<%= form_tag attach_photo_location_path(@location), method: :put, multipart: true do %>
  <%= label_tag :photo %>
  <%= file_field_tag :photo %>

  <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

**Also:**

Change `post` to `put` method, We are updating not creating [Idempotency](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html)

```
resources :locations do
  member do
    put :attach_photo
  end
end
```

Comment: I read this comment before while using form_for - I still made this mistake and I also had `multipart: true` set... however it was not set in the `html: ` options, so it literally didn't do anything and thus left the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute out. It took me a long time to realize I had to move it and before that, for me to realize I should check if the `enctype=` html attribute was being generated.

Comment: @Nitrodist `form_for` doesnt generate, thats why i have used `form_tag` in the sample

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the signature (in `params[:signed_blob_id]`) to the instance as the example from [the docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/One.html#method-i-attach) illustrates.

So, like this:

```
@location.photos.attach(params[:signed_blob_id]) # Signed reference to blob from direct upload
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue using this

```rb
  def user_params
    params.permit(
      :id, :name, :email, :username, :country, :avatar, :id_number, :license_number
    ).select {|x,v| v.present?}
  end
```

Looks like the empty value is causing the issue `"avatar"=>""`

```rb
 "id_number"=>"234545", "license_number"=>"234545", "avatar"=>""
```

---

My model

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :avatar
```

Answer (score 0):

**Rails Active Storage + React Native + React Native debugger with Network Inspect Enabled may cause this error.**

If you're using [React Native debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) with `Network Inspect Enabled`, file uploading might not be working because of this known issue: [Formdata sends [object object] in request](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/38).

Turn off `Network Inspect` when you're using React Native debugger. You can inspect network payload with Reactotron instead.