# How can I set wrapper data from a FormData?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, multipartform-data, form-data

How can I set wrapper data from a FormData ?

I use CarrierWave in Rails.
I'm calling a WebAPI from ajax.

This command has been successful.

```
curl -X POST \
https://site-url/api/books/ \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
-F 'book[title]=test' \
-F book[image]=@kindle_3_0_library_ipad_iphone.jpg \
-F 'book[genre_id]=1'
```

This is the development.log at that time.

```
Parameters: {"book"=>{"title"=>"test", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000005f1d790 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20181016-37646-65mtjc.jpg>, @original_filename="kindle_3_0_library_ipad_iphone.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"book[image]\"; filename=\"kindle_3_0_library_ipad_iphone.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "genre_id"=>"1"}}
```

This code fails.

```
var request = new FormData();
request.append('title', title);
request.append('image', imageFile, imageFile.name);
request.append('genre_id', 1);
```

This is the development.log at that time.

```
Parameters: {"title"=>"test", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f01dc083240 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20181016-37646-3zmceu.jpg>, @original_filename="41fQlZLtDgL._SX337_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"41fQlZLtDgL._SX337_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "genre_id"=>"1"}
```

Other tried this.

```
var request = new Object();
request.book = new FormData();
request.book.append('title', title);
request.book.append('image', imageFile, imageFile.name);
request.book.append('genre_id', 1);
```

This is the development.log at that time.

```
Parameters: {"object Object"=>nil}
```

I don't know how to set parameters that can be saved.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem resolved.

```
request.append('book[title]', title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Form data supposed to have a header with `multipart/form-data`.

```
const formData = new FormData();
const config = {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}

axios.post("/URL", formData, config)
    .then(...)
```

This link also about that, quite different question.
[ActiveStorage and Image upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483901/rails-activestorage-error-messageverifier-invalidsignature/51113082#51113082)

Comment: It is already set.  
I have thought different problem.  

    Request Headers
    Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 15
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Comment: Post yr ajaxing line maybe!